# Applying Case 3 Of The Master Theorem

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, clrs

Introduction to Algorithms CLRS 4.3 (b) has the problem

*T(n) = 3*T(n/3) + n/lg(n)*

Note that
*n^(log a/ log b) = n^(log 3/ log 3) = 1*

The book states that here the master theorem case 3 cannot be applied since n/log (n) is not polynomially larger i.e. it is asymptotically less than n^(k) where k is any positive constant.

My question is: Let's take k = 0.1 then n/log (n) is always asymptotically greater than n^(0.1), but this is contradicting the above statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```f(n) / n^(logba) = (n/logn) / n = 1/logn```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have a mistake in applying the antecedent of case 3.

Your recurrence is

*T(n) = 3 T(n/3) + n/lg(n)*

which, in the [conventions of the Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) means that *a = b = 3*

For [the third case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_3), you must have *n / log(n) = Ω(n<sup>c</sup>)*, where *c > log<sub>3</sub>(3) = 1*. This indeed does not apply here.